# Trouble understanding strtok()

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const string PROMPT = "prompt> ";
const char PIPE_DEL[3] = "||";

bool checkInput(char []);


bool checkInput(char cmd[]){
    string command = cmd;
    transform(command.begin(), command.end(), command.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (command == "q" || command == "quit")
        return true;
    else
        return false;   
}




int main(){
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true){
        char command[1024];
        pid_t pid;

        cout << '\n' << iteration << '\n';
        cout << PROMPT;
        cin >> command;

        if ( checkInput(command) )
            break;

        char* token = strtok(command, PIPE_DEL);
        vector<string> commands;
        commands.push_back(token);


        cout << "command 1: " << commands[0] << "\n";
        iteration ++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

1) " " is counted as a delimiter!
Correct me if I'm wrong but the only thing counted as a delimiter are the things inside the string in the second argument. that isn't the case here since I have no " " in my delimiter string but it is counted as such.

2) Why is the execution order all out of whack?
If there are two tokens the program skips some code.

Here is some output:

> prompt> hello
>   command 1: hello
>
> 1

This is expected. There are no characters in that match the delimiter, the whole string is then printed out.

> prompt> hello world
>
> command 1: hello
>
> 1
>
> prompt>   command 1: world
>
> 2

This is totally unexpected. First of all " " isn't a delimiter. Second why is cin being skipped? Why is the cout statement that is printing the first delimiter running before cin is? Why is input the second token? For example running this:

> prompt> hello quit
>
> command 1: hello
>
> 1

terminates the program (if cin reads 'q' or 'quit' the program terminates). This kinda proves cin is being ignored or at least not working as I'm expecting. cin should stop, read from console and put that into the array command. However, command holds 'quit' which is expected since strtok() modifies the input string, but this should be overridden with.

> char command[1024];

3) Last output

> prompt> hello || world
>
> command 1: hello
>
> 1
>
> prompt> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>
> 'std::logic_error'   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not
>
> valid Aborted

Again " " isn't a delimiter. Token 1 should be "hello " token 2 (if i decide to parse it) should be " world". This error shouldn't exist.

Comment: Don't try to understand it - there is no possible reason for using it in C++ code.

Comment: Fair enough! Do you recommend an alternative for c++ @NeilButterworth?

Comment: Use the features of std::string, use std::stringstr eam, write your own parser  - anything but strtok - it's useless even in C, for many reasons, the main being one that it modifies its input, so it  can't be const correct, and that it doesn't do anything particularly useful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth thanks I used your advice and corrected my code. the find function is definitely more straightforward than strtok().

Comment: This doesn’t address the immediate problem, but note that `strtok` Looks for a **single character** from the delimiter list, not the entire list. So `”||”` is redundant, and will match a single `’|’` character. `”|^”` would match the first occurrence of a `’|’` **or** a `’^’`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the responses I was able to get around the issues I was having. Here is what I did:

```
const string PROMPT = "prompt> ";
const string PIPE_DEL = "||";

bool checkInput(string);


bool checkInput(string command){
    transform(command.begin(), command.end(), command.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (command == "q" || command == "quit")
        return true;
    else
        return false;   
}


vector<string> getCommands(string command){
    vector<string> commands;

    size_t tokenStart = 0, tokenEnd;
    while ( (tokenEnd = command.find(PIPE_DEL, tokenStart)) != string::npos ){
        commands.push_back(command.substr(tokenStart, tokenEnd - tokenStart));
        tokenStart = tokenEnd + PIPE_DEL.length();
    }
    commands.push_back(command.substr(tokenStart, command.length()));

    return commands;
}




int main(){
    int iteration = 0;
    while (true){
        string command;
        pid_t pid;

        cout << '\n' << iteration << endl;
        cout << PROMPT;
        getline(cin, command);

        if ( checkInput(command) )
            break;

        vector<string> commands = getCommands(command);

        iteration ++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where as before there were character arrays I'm strictly using string objects. I am also using the find function from the string class to parse delimiters instead of strtok(). Finally, cin doesn't parse spaces correctly. I replaced it with:

```
getline(cin, command);
```

However as @Christophe pointed out you can also use:

```
cin.getline(command,1024);
```

where command in this case is a character array and 1024 is the number of characters to read.

Comment: Re: “cin doesn’t parse spaces correctly” — more accurately, stream extractors (`operator >>`) don’t parse spaces **the way you want them to**.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

First the extractor `cin>>command;` will stop at the first space received.  If you want to get a full line, you'd need to do:

```
    cin.getline(command,1024);
```

Then, you may still face a problem if there's no more input or in case of an error, since you always execute what follows, even if no input was received.  The best would be to rewrite your loop logic, so that you loop on:

```
    while (cin.getline(command,1024)) { 
    ...
    }
```

Then [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) doesn't work with multiple chars as you expect.  In fact, it expects different delimiters, that each could make the end of a token.  But the end of the token in your input will only be ONE of the list.

Finally, you push only one the first token into your `commands` vector.

*Remark: using strtok() is not the best idea.  A better option would be to use strings throughout your code, and use algorithms to find separators, for example [like this](https://ideone.com/JQjU1T)*

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did figure the cin issue not too long ago. You are correct! The way I had cin doesn't parse spaces as I was expecting. What I used was getline(cin, command) where command is a string (just so others have options). I have since used the find function instead of strtok(). I'll post it here so others can use it. Thanks again, man!